# Date and time in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

my data looks like this:

```
06.02.2013;13:00;0,215;0,215;0,185;0,205;0,00
```

I try to read it this way:
`s = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, sep=';', skiprows=3, index_col=[0],decimal=',',thousands='.',parse_dates={'Date': [0, 1]}, dayfirst=True)`

(see http://www.nuclearphynance.com/Show%20Post.aspx?PostIDKey=164080
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2586)

This is what I get:

```
6022013.0 13:00       0.215  0.215  0.185    0.205        0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, the thousands argument doesn't seem to work. Created a [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4322).

Comment: I agree, it's a bug. The date is also stripped of `.` because of the thousands separator. If you remove it, it will work. To circumvent the bug without giving up the thousands separator, you can add a date parser that will read the date without dots.

Comment: I see it is a bug. I use version 0.11.0. I am wondering what is the best way to work around the bug since I don't want to wait until it is fixed. I have stocks larger than 1000 and therefore need to specify the thousands-separator.

Answer (score 2):

This was a [bug fixed in pandas 0.13+](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4322) (thanks to this issue):

```
In [11]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=';', header=None, parse_dates={'Dates': [0, 1]},
                     index_col=0, decimal=',', thousands=".")
Out[11]:
                            2      3      4      5  6
Dates
2013-06-02 13:00:00  1000.215  0.215  0.185  0.205  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a bug. See below,

My data file looks like so,

```
date; time; col1; col2; col3; col4; col5
06.02.2013 ; 13:00 ; 0,215 ; 0,215 ; 0,185 ; 0,205 ; 0,00
06.02.2013 ; 13:00 ; 0,215 ; 0,215 ; 0,185 ; 0,205 ; 0,00
```

I implement the following code on it,

```
import pandas
s = pandas.read_csv('test.txt', decimal=',',sep=';', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])
print s
```

To get,

```
               time   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
date                                                  
2013-06-02   13:00   0.215  0.215  0.185  0.205      0
2013-06-02   13:00   0.215  0.215  0.185  0.205      0
```

Is this the result you want.

Please make sure that you are using the latest pandas version

```
'0.11.0'
```

To deal with the thousands operators... you could use

```
s = pandas.read_csv('test2.txt',sep=';',decimal=',', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0],converters={'col1':lambda x: float(x.replace('.','').replace(',','.'))})
```

Comment: Yes, however your example does not have values larger than 1000. For this my data has a point as thousands-separator. Try the following:date; time; col1; col2; col3; col4; col5
06.02.2013 ; 13:00 ; 1.045,215 ; 0,215 ; 0,185 ; 0,205 ; 0,00
06.02.2013 ; 13:00 ; 0,215 ; 0,215 ; 2.156,185 ; 0,205 ; 0,00 and with that youo will get the values larger than 1000 as strings using your code.

Comment: OK.. you probably need to convert the thousands operator to remove it by using converters... like so, s = pandas.read_csv('test2.txt',sep=';',decimal=',', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0],converters={'col1':lambda x: float(x.replace('.','').replace(',','.'))})... I have updated my answer to reflect the new code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when running your example file date-parsing works. However, my data looks like this:

```
Datum;Zeit;Er<F6>ffnung;Hoch;Tief;Schluss;Volumen
02.08.2013;14:00;8.428,58;8.431,67;8.376,28;8.406,94;73.393.682,00
01.08.2013;14:00;8.320,38;8.411,30;8.316,89;8.410,73;97.990.435,00
```

In that case, date does not get recognized:

```
s = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', decimal=',',sep=';', parse_dates=True, index_col=[0])
print s
....                                                            
02.08.2013  14:00  8.428,58  8.431,67  8.376,28  8.406,94   73.393.682,00
01.08.2013  14:00  8.320,38  8.411,30  8.316,89  8.410,73   97.990.435,00
```

For me the only difference between your file and mine is the missing spaces between the separators `;`?